# pandoc from RSudio Server not recognized when running script via cron

Tags: r, cron, r-markdown, pandoc, rstudio-server

On a server, I want cron to run an R script which renders an HTML page using rmarkdown. RStudio server is installed. The crontab entry for user `mark` is:

```
* * * * * Rscript R/test.R >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1
```

**test.R:**

```
library(rmarkdown)
getwd()
render("R/test.Rmd")
```

The `cron.log` file shows

```
[1] "/home/mark"
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found.
Execution stopped
```

Running `test.R` from the console, however, works fine:

```
Rscript R/test.R
```

The RStudio server version of `pandoc` was added to `usr/local/bin` using a symlink as [described here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md)). Checking the pandoc version in the console gives

```
mark@myserver:$ pandoc -v
pandoc 1.15.2
```

which is not the old version as in the log file. Also, the binary appears to be found

```
mark@myserver:$ which pandoc
/usr/local/bin/pandoc
```

I am not sure what is going on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that `/usr/local/bin` is being added to your `$PATH` in your bash shell, but that your cron job is not running under bash and so doesn't have pandoc on the path. To test this assumption, add these lines to your R file:

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
Sys.which("pandoc")
```

If that's indeed the case, you could have your R script append to `$PATH` as appropriate, or have cron run the job under a bash shell.

If all else fails, you could set `RSTUDIO_PANDOC`:

```
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = "/usr/local/bin/pandoc")
```

Comment: I finally added `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc")` to my script. Working! Thanks